# Is it possible to crawl IBM DB2 database from AWS glue

Tags: aws-glue

I need to read the xml file and load it to DB2 database in AWS glue.

Is it possible to establish connection to DB2 in AWS glue?

Answer (score 2):

You can't create Glue Crawlers or build a data catalog for an IBM DB2 source but you can directly access DB2 tables using a JDBC driver. You won't create a connection. The IBM databases are directly connected via the Glue job. For more details and demo refer the following link :

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/big-data/use-aws-glue-to-run-etl-jobs-against-non-native-jdbc-data-sources/

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible yet. 
The connection types supported are present here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-etl-connect.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Is there any ways that i can read the xml and write it to DB2 using AWS glue - Apache pyspark?

Comment: May be you should accept the answer and ask another one for separate question.